# Mysql update where each updated row has an increasing number

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to run a MySql query that updates certain rows, but gives the updated value in each row an increasing value.

I looked into stored procedures for this but I was not able to create such a procedure.

Here is a sample to help you better understand what i want to achieve:

The table

```
id     text        myCustomValue       myMatchValue
1      Test1       1                   a
2      Test2       2                   a
3      Test3       3                   a      
4      Test4       1                   b
5      Test5       1                   c
6      Test6       2                   b
7      Test7       3                   b
```

My custom query should basically achieve this:

```
UPDATE table SET myCustomValue = increasingNumberStartingAt_5 WHERE myMatchValue = a;
```

With this query the result would be:

```
id     text        myCustomValue       myMatchValue
1      Test1       5                   a
2      Test2       6                   a
3      Test3       7                   a      
4      Test4       1                   b
5      Test5       1                   c
6      Test6       2                   b
7      Test7       3                   b
```

I need this because the table is large and thus I cannot run many queries to the database to update each row individually. I could send multiple statements at once, but it seems like there should be a much simpler solution that i just cannot think of.

Comment: What wrong with your query? Just change it to : set myCustomValue = myCustomValue + 4 where myMatchValue = 'a'

Comment: @Yossi It's not a real query. It's just supposed to explain what I want to achieve. Take a look at the result. it updated 3 rows with different values.

Comment: Yes but as you can see they are all +4 then what the used to be! So, whats wrong with your example query?

Comment: @Yossi Oh right. I should have explained better. myMatchValue can change. After such a change i will have duplicate myCustomValues, which should be basically reindexed starting at a certain value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
UPDATE mytable e,
   (SELECT @n := 4) m
SET e.myCustomValue = @n := @n + 1 
WHERE e.myMatchValue ='a'
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a2e9f/1)

Comment: The simplicity of this is amazing.

Comment: @MichaelFrey This won't update `myCustomValue` in ascending order according to `id`. If this isn't a requirement, then this is the query for you.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos thank you for that explanation. The order is not important in my case so I have chosen this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id, @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn
   FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 4) AS var
   WHERE myMatchValue = 'a'
   ORDER BY id
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id   
SET t1.myCustomValue = t2.rn
```

The above `UPDATE` statement uses an `INNER JOIN` to a derived table that uses a variable in order to enumerate *matching* records of the table. The first matching record is assigned a value of 5, next record a value of 6, etc.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e282b/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
   UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            T1.ID,
            @a := @a + 1 AS incr
        FROM
            (SELECT @a := 4) sl,
            YOUR_TABLE T1
        INNER JOIN YOUR_TABLE T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
        WHERE
            T1.myMatchValue = 'a'
    ) filteredTable ON YOUR_TABLE.ID = filteredTable.ID
    SET YOUR_TABLE.myCustomValue = filteredTable.incr;
```

[**RUNNING SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34f18/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
    SET @start_at = 4; -- 1 minus your desired start point
    UPDATE
      my_table a
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
        id, @start_at := @start_at + 1 AS _row
      FROM
        my_table
      WHERE
        myMatchValue = 'a' ) b
    ON
      a.id = b.id
    SET
      a.myCustomValue = b._row;
```

Here: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51887/2)